# How to filter/narrow XML in Perl to ignore unwanted child elements?

Tags: xml, perl, mojolicious

Say I have the following XML structure (mock) that begins:

```
<site defaultDomain="www.somedomain.com">
    <supported-locales>
        <locale id="sometext"/>
    </supported-locales>
    <next-child-of-site>
    ...
</site>
```

I am using [`Mojo::DOM`](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::DOM) and trying to get only the `id` text of `<locale>` elements that are children of `<supported-locales>` elements and ignore all other children of `<site>`

```
# Parse XML
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse($xml);

for my $e ($dom->find('site[defaultDomain')->each) {
    say $e->children->join();
}
```

So I get this far, but am stuck on how to filter the children to `<supported-locales>` and then `<locale>` only. Suggestions? I'm new to XML processing with `Mojo::DOM`.

Comment: Is that suppose to be an XPath? If so, you want `//site/supported-locales/locale/@id`

Comment: I don't think Mojo::DOM supports XPath, only CSS selectors.

Comment: It's fine to publish “mock” data as long as it displays the error your'e asking about. In this case your sample is too small and isn't even valid XML. Likewise, the CSS selector `site[defaultDomain` in your code is incorrect. Is this the real code that you've shown us?

Comment: Does it have to be `Mojo::DOM`? Because both `XML::Twig` and `XML::LibXML` are excellent.

Comment: @Borodin, thanks, it is meant to be an excerpt of the XML, not the whole file; also `site[defaultDomain` was a typo

Comment: @Sobrique, no but I tried those first and couldn't "grok" their docs as easily

Answer (score 3):

You can look for `locale` tags that are underneath `site` and `supported-locales` tags directly using the child selector:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);
use Mojo::DOM;

my $xml = q{
<site defaultDomain="www.somedomain.com">
    <supported-locales>
        <locale id="sometext"/>
    </supported-locales>
    <next-child-of-site>
</site>
};
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse($xml);

for my $e ($dom->find('site > supported-locales > locale')->each) {
   say $e->{id};
}
# output: sometext
```

As always, you should `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

Comment: Ah selectors! Thanks Hunter, I will give this a try.

Comment: Take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM::CSS#SELECTORS for more documentation on CSS selectors.

Comment: @sqldoug: *"selectors!"* indeed. I would use *Mojolicious* all the time if it supported XPath expressions as well. But CSS selectors are essential for locating HTML elements of a given class, which may look like `<div class="abc ba c d">`. CSS allows just `div.c` whereas in XPath 1.0 even `div[contains(@class, "c")]` doesn't work because it will pick up the `c` in `abc`

Comment: @Borodin, thanks; indeed that is interesting. Mojo seems simpler, for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem seems to be that you have an invalid CSS selector `site[defaultDomain`. It doesn't have balanced square brackets so it's not even a legitimate XPath expression

Here's a program that uses your own data to provide what I think you're asking for

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Mojo;

my $xml = do {
    local $/;
    <DATA>;
};

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1);

$dom->parse($xml);

for my $e ($dom->find('supported-locales > locale')->each) {
    say $e->attr('id');
}

__DATA__
<site defaultDomain="www.somedomain.com">
  <supported-locales>
    <locale id="sometext"/>
  </supported-locales>
  <next-child-of-site>
  </next-child-of-site>
</site>
```

#### output

```
sometext
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that was a typo.